What is this kind of gate in the US and Canada called?
On the Internet, I have seen many names such as revolving gate, turnstile gate, revolving gate with turnstiles or just turnstile.
I don't really trust every source on the Internet because there are many non-native speakers running websites where they sell their products.
Thank you in advance! :-)


I don't know that we have a universal name for them. I think all four of those options are things somebody might reasonably use.

Thank you so much!:-)

I agree with @Kaia - as a native speaker living in the US northeast, I don't think there's a single correct name for this item. Much of the US/canada doesn't have this item at all - I've only really seen them in high-density areas like really big cities, and I suspect the name for them may vary regionally.

Where did you find the image?

The whole device is called a turnstile. A turnstile is a kind of revolving gate.  No need to add the word "gate" after it.

Thanks but what if I still added gate to turnstile? Would that be too unnatural and redundant?Turnstile conjures up a different image in my head. Turnstiles tend to be much lower as far as I know. Also what about the term ''revolving gate''??

Honestly I think "revolving gate" or "turnstile gate" are fine, regardless of whether they're the proper term. The problem is that we just don't talk about this specific kind of thing very often, so you're likely to just have to describe it or say something like "you know, one of those spinny gate thingies, you'll know it when you see it."

You need to cite the website.

I updated my answer with two types of revolving door (with and without a turnstile) and a turnstile that is waist high.  These are not called gates (I mean the ones like in your picture.

Turnstiles
The image you have attached is of a turnstile.(USA, Canada, UK)
The purpose is to automate the entry and exit. Only one person can  pass through these gates at a time so they are typically used to reinforce a one-way stream of traffic or to restrict entry to those who insert a coin, ticket or pass of some kind.
The Oxford dictionary meaning of a turnstile = a metal gate that moves round in a circle when it is pushed, and allows one person at a time to enter a place.
The term 'revolving gates' cannot be used to describe it as it is a general term. While the word 'turnstile' is enough to convey what you have in mind. The other words+ revolving, gates etc are superfluous
But as they are available in various designs, they are described differently.
The image shown is a Full height turnstile.
Types of turnstiles include 1. Tripod turnstile 2. Swing turnstile 3. Flap barrier turnstile 4. Full height turnstile 5. Sliding turnstile 6. Speed gate turnstile 7. Half height turnstile 8. Drom arm turnstile
Note : The terms described here are technical terms understood by majority of the manufacturers in Europe and US.

I don't think most native speakers would be able to identify the difference between a speed gate turnstile and a drom arm turnstile. If you really need to disambiguate, I'd think arbitrary adjectives are more likely than specific type names.

Our company in Dubai was dealing in this. Turnstile is a common term in Europe and US. Those are various models of turnstiles, the purpose is the same.

So revolving gate is incorrect and unnatural?

I have used the technical terms used by the manufacturers of turnstiles. As mentioned by you the common man uses various terms. If you wish to know the correct terms I suggest that you visit the turnstile manufacturers sites in Canada (Google search). My search showed these results -

https://www.grainger.ca/en/category/turnstiles/access-barriers-and-crowd-control/c/18649
https://www.alvaradomfg.com/product-c/secured-entry-control/?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9vqyBhCKARIsAIIcLMGtmihw9yEJ6NYKuMyqdtkL2p1ffyzwkCDqkafjo5LtZ6Y3sNBbcwoaApbjEALw_wcB


No, it is an revolving door.

Turnstiles per se are not set into a revolving door. It is an industry wide term: revolving door. And this one happens to contain a turnstile. There are different models of revolving doors.

It is not a gate. It is a type of entrance to a building.

TURNSTILE REVOLVING DOOR
from: © 2024 MairsTurnstile-Online.
Here is a regular turnstile. from an old MBTA line (Boston) from a Wikipedia image:

Not all revolving doors have a turnstile
Here is a revolving door without a turnstile:


@JamesMathai No, it is not. Those without turnstiles are called revolving doors. Google it and you will see. And it's very used to describe politicians going back and forth with the private sector. I cannot believe the downvotes. The picture by the OP comes from the people who sell it.

Are you referring to the image you sent? Or Is it revolving glass doors? Revolving glass doors are used in shopping complexes. It's purpose is different. I also don't understand why people down vote. It is discouraging. Be democratic and let's have a healthy debate.

@JamesMathai There are three things here: A revolving door (general term, see my edited answer), a revolving door with a turnstile AND a regular waist-high turnstile. They all are used to control entry to a place.

The third picture is of a revolving glass door - which can be used to control entry. It's main purpose is to prevent hot air and dust to enter inside.

@JamesMathai Whoever dv'ed me is mistaken. There are two types of revolving doors and one that is just a turnstile, if the first were not that (turnstile revolving door)  it would not be being marketed under that term. The purpose is not that in a cold climate. It also keeps out the cold in winter and keep the cool air from AC inside in the summer.

At some places, they do use the word - door for all doors and gate. In Arabic it is the word baab. In German there is only slight difference tor and tur. But normally in maximum cases, the word "door' is used when it is completely closed like the revolving glass door or the sliding glass door.

+1 Yes it is wrong so I gave a vote because the term is mentioned in the manufacturers site as you stated. I also mentioned earlier that different people use different terms.
